# Кол-во разрядов после запятой. Python

Tags: python, математика, float

Есть число `a` типа `float`
Надо определить кол-во знаков после запятой в этом числе. 
Например, для `a = 0.25` это 2.

Comment: Число `a` типа `float`: `1e-30`. Сколько у него знаков после запятой?

Comment: Чему по вашему равно: `0.1 .as_integer_ratio()`? 1/10? Почему? Попробуйте ответ записать прежде чем запустить это выражение в REPL. Сколько знаков после запятой вы ожидаете для этого числа (`0.1`)? Сколько знаков по вашему должно содержать 1/3, представленное как float? Сколько знаков после запятой вы хотите для результата выражения: `0.1+0.2`? [Что нужно знать про арифметику с плавающей запятой](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/112953/)

Comment: str(32.123456)[::-1].find('.') # 6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231755/count-decimal-places-in-a-float

Comment: @vadimvaduxa: число в строке и число типа float это очень разные вещи. Сравните: `Decimal('0.1')` и `Decimal(0.1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jfs верно заметил, что число типа float может принимать разные формы: оно может быть такого вида: `1e-5`. И если сложить

```
0.1 + 0.2
```

Результат будет не совсем таким, который можно предсказать.

```
0.30000000000000004
```

А тут `0.1` после единицы вообще сколько угодно нолей может быть.

В любом случае, вам без преобразования числа в строку никак не найти количество знаков после запятой.

Поэтому я предлагаю следующий код, чтобы не повторяться с предыдущими ответами:

```
number = 123.123123
s = str(number)
print(abs(s.find('.') - len(s)) - 1)
```

Преобразовываем в функцию:

```
def get_count(number):
    s = str(number)
    if '.' in s:
        return abs(s.find('.') - len(s)) - 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: `str(0.00000001)` - это `'1e-08'`, в котором нет точки. Результат 0 ошибочен, должно быть 8.

Answer (score 5):

```
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal(str(0.25)).as_tuple().exponent*(-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> print(len(str(math.pi).split('.')[1])) # 15
```

Comment: Пока писал свой костыль думал что-то не так делаю -- увидел ваш ответ и понял, что забыл про `split`, но менять ответ уже не буду -- одинаковый код получится :)

Comment: @gil9red можно это еще регуляркой делать, но это уже странно)

Answer (score 1):

Если через строки, то:

```
def get_precision(f):
    str_f = str(f)
    if '.' not in str_f:
        return 0

    # Получение строки после точки и возвращение ее длины
    return len(str_f[str_f.index('.') + 1:])


print(get_precision(0.25))  # 2
print(get_precision(0.345))  # 3

import math
# pi = 3.141592653589793
print(get_precision(math.pi))  # 15
```

Comment: Так как это `float` то будет минимум 1 знак после точки.

Comment: @Alban, ну мало ли что туда передадут :D

Comment: `str(0.00000001)` - это float  '1e-08', в котором нет точки. Код падает с `ValueError: substring not found`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_dot_count(number):
    return (len(str(float(number))[str(float(number)).index('.')+1:]) 
            if str(float(number))[str(float(number)).index('.')+1:]!='0' 
            else 0)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Даже небольшое пояснение может существенно облегчить понимание предложенного решения.

Answer (score 0):

Без преобразования в строку (и тому подобного):

```
def fractional_part_len(number_to_count):
    count = 0
    
    while number_to_count % 1 != 0:
        number_to_count *= 10
        count += 1
    
    return count
```

```
print(fractional_part_len(0.25))  # 2
print(fractional_part_len(1e-5))  # 5
print(fractional_part_len(256))  # 0
```